# define python logger in one script and use it in all other scripts

Tags: python-2.7, logging

I have two python scripts and one more python file which contains common functions used by these scripts.
I want to define a logger function in this common file and want to use these loggers in test scripts.
Can anyone please provide the best solution on how to define this logger in common file and use it in all other files?
Please correct if my examples are wrong. :)

Ex: 
Common file: (common.py)
This file should have a logger with name "logtool" which can be used by all scripts

My test script 1: (test1.py)

```
logtool.info("some text")
logtool.debug("Some text")
```

My test script 2: (test2.py)

```
logtool.info("Some text")
logtool.debug("Some text")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the following code in your common.py file -

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M',
                    filename='logger.log',
                    filemode='w', )
logtool = logging.getLogger('MainLogs')
logtool.setLevel(logging.INFO)
fh = logging.FileHandler('logger.log')
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logtool.addHandler(ch)
```

Then, simply import logger in other scripts -

```
from common import logtool
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly.

Comment: I am glad it helped. Please upvote and accept  my answer.